# Solving $x'(t)=-3(x(t))^{4/3}\sin(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x'(t)=-3(x(t))^{4/3}\sin(t)$$
I can't find my mistake:
\begin{align}&\frac{dx}{dt}=-3x^{4/3}\sin(t) \\\Leftrightarrow&\ \int\frac{1}{x^{4/3}}dx=-3\int \sin(t) dt\\\Leftrightarrow&\ -3 \frac{1}{x^{1/3}}=3 \cos(t)+c_1 \\\Leftrightarrow&\ x=(\frac{1}{c_2-\cos(t)})^3 \end{align}

According to wolfram alpha the solution should be $x(t)=-\frac{27}{(c+3\cos(t))^3}$

Comment: Why do you think your solution and Wolfram's solution are different?

Comment: The "difference" is only in the constants: $c_2$ in your solution, and $c$ in theirs. Plug in $c_2 = -c/3$ and you'll have the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed not wrong. notice that:

$$\left( \frac{1}{C- \cos(x)} \right)^3 = - \left(\frac{3}{3 \cos(x) - 3C} \right)^3 = -\frac{27}{(3 \cos(x) + C')^3}$$

The misunderstanding arises from the fact that you see those $C$ equal, but they're not. I called one $C'$ to point that out. The thing is, in these cases every constant gets renamed as $C$ after every passage, so $-3C=C$ in that sense

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\frac{27}{3^3} = \frac1{1^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$-\frac{1}{3}x(t)^{1/3}= \frac{1}{3cos(t)+c_1}$

Multiply both sides by a constant to simplify the equation, in this case that would be by -3. You'll have:

$x(t)^{1/3}= \frac{3}{3cos(t)+c_1}$

I think now it's clear where you made the mistake. There is none, it's just written differently.